# How to update a array of numbers in mongoose

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am unable to update an array inside of a document in MongoDB (Mongoose). Here is my definition for a stock model.

```
const ticker = new mongoose.Schema({
   ticker: String,
   Price: Number,
   Amount: Number,
   PastPrices: [Number]
});
export const stock = mongoose.model("Stocks", ticker);
```

Here is one document in MongoDB

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61e5d0e1dfda4d7c85dc8fe2"
  },
  "PastPrices": [
    2
  ],
  "ticker": "TSLA",
  "Price": 2,
  "Amount": 0,
  "__v": 0
}
```

I am running this in mongoose and the PastPrices is not updating. I want to be able to push every few seconds into this array and then render it into a chart

```
 stock.updateOne({ticker: "TSLA"},
        { $push: { PastPrices:1}}
    );
```

I am not getting any error thrown but it is just not updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct, but in order for the query to return updated data, you need to pass additional config `{ new: true }`. If you don't pass it, the query will update the data, but it will return old data.

```js
stock.updateOne(
  { ticker: "TSLA" },
  { $push: { PastPrices:1 } },
  { new: true }
);
```

Comment: I just added that part to the end of my query and the database is not updating. Am I supposed to have additional code to then send it to the database?

Comment: Did you check if you have the document in DB with the value of "TSLA"?

Comment: `{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61e5d0e1dfda4d7c85dc8fe2"
  },
  "PastPrices": [
    2
  ],
  "ticker": "TSLA",
  "Price": 2,
  "Amount": 0,
  "__v": 0
}` That is in my mongoDB database

Comment: Maybe you have multiple documents with `"ticker": "TSLA"`. Can you check that? `updateOne` will find the first document it matches and update that one.

Comment: I did check and there was only one TSLA. I just got it to update, the issue was I didn't do .exec at the end of the query

Answer (score 1):

`updateOne` returns a [Query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html), which doesn't execute your update immediately. From the [Mongoose guide for Queries](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries) it states:

> A mongoose query can be executed in one of two ways. First, if you pass in a callback function, Mongoose will execute the query asynchronously and pass the results to the callback.
>
> A query also has a .then() function, and thus can be used as a promise.

Meaning you can pass a callback function as in the [documentation for executing Queries](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#executing):

> ```
> const Person = mongoose.model('Person', yourSchema);
> // find each person with a last name matching 'Ghost', selecting the `name` and > `occupation` fields
> Person.findOne({ 'name.last': 'Ghost' }, 'name occupation', function (err, person) {
>  if (err) return handleError(err);
>  // Prints "Space Ghost is a talk show host".
>   console.log('%s %s is a %s.', person.name.first, person.name.last,
>     person.occupation);
> });
> ```

You can also use [`then`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-then) or [`exec`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-exec) if you want to use Promises. From the [Mongoose documentation for promises](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises):

> ```
> const query = Band.findOne({name: "Guns N' Roses"});
> assert.ok(!(query instanceof Promise));
>
>  // A query is not a fully-fledged promise, but it does have a `.then()`.
> query.then(function(doc) {
>  // use doc
> });
>
> // `.exec()` gives you a fully-fledged promise
> const promise = Band.findOne({name: "Guns N' Roses"}).exec();
> assert.ok(promise instanceof Promise);
>
> promise.then(function (doc) {
>   // use doc
> });
> ```

If in an async method, you can also `await` the query:

```
await stock.updateOne({ticker: "TSLA"},
        { $push: { PastPrices:1}}
    );
```

Comment: Im a little bit confused where the parameters are coming from with the callback approach. `You use function (err, person)`  without defining what type it is. Furthermore, what would I put inside of the callback function if I just wanted to update the database?

Comment: The callback for [updateOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-updateOne) has two parameters, `(error, writeOpResult)`, where `writeOpResult` is the `result` object documented [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#~writeOpCallback). @SarthakSin